# Not able to expect `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` with different parameters

Tags: jestjs

I have mocked the MongoDB instance `updateOne`. in this code, i spyOn the `UpdateByID` which calls updateOne. For a success case, the `writeById` method calls  `UpdateByID` two times. so I was expecting `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` two times with different parameters. But when I run my code it was expecting the same value with two times. Can anyone suggest to me what wrong in my code?

**Test case File**

```
const mongoDBInstance = new MongoDb(
        new MongoClient('testClient'),
        {
            updateOne: jest.fn(),

        } as unknown as Collection
    );

it('should perform writeById on mongodb if parameters are valid.', async () => {
            // Preparing
            const mockUpdateByIdReturn = {
                result: {ok: 1, n: 1, nModified: 1},
                connection: 0,
                matchedCount: 1,
                modifiedCount: 1,
                upsertedCount: 0,
                upsertedId: {_id: id}
            };
            const validDocument = { string_field : 'sample'};
            // Executing
            const spyUpdateByID = jest.spyOn(MongoDb.prototype, 'updateById')
                .mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(mockUpdateByIdReturn)) // updateById -> updateOne - document
                .mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({} as any)); // updateById -> updateOne - createAutoFieldsForUpdateRequest
            const result = await model.writeById(id, validDocument, EndpointType.UPDATE);
            // Verifying
            expect(result).toEqual({
                type: 'success',
                message: 'ModuleA Updated Success Constant.',
                statusCode: 204
            });
            expect(spyUpdateByID).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, id, validDocument);
            expect(spyUpdateByID).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, id, {update_auto_field: new Date()});
            // Clearing
            spyUpdateByID.mockClear();
        });
```

**Model File**  (In this method the updateAutoFields also calls `updateById` )

```
  writeById = async (id: string | ObjectId, document: Partial<ModelType>):
        Promise<ValidationError | ResponseErrorMessageType | ResponseSuccessMessageType> => {
        let mongodb: MongoDb<ModelType>;
        // Update data
        mongodb = await MongoDb.connect(<string>this.schemaConstants['collectionName']);
        const dbResponse: UpdateWriteOpResult = await mongodb.updateById(id, <ModelType>modelDocument);
        mongodb.close();
        // Update auto fields
        await ModelUtility.updateAutoFields(id, (<AbstractBuilder<ModelType>><unknown>modelDocument));
        return <ResponseSuccessMessageType>this.successConstants.updatedSuccessfully;
    };
```

[image]

Comment: I ran into the same problem, it's a bug in what's being displayed as far as I can tell. I had an error in my asserted arguments. Once I resolved that, the test passed. To see what was passed in, debug spyUpdateById.mock.calls.

Comment: @Boland this should be THE answer, thanks for this you have resolved my hours and hours of anguish